# Python: correct usage of triple quotes

Tags: python

My code doesn't run if I use triple quotes before an else statement:

```
def do_something(test_option=False):
    """
    function to do something
    :param test_option: bool
    :return: None
    """
    
    '''
    Testing
    '''
    
    if test_option==True:
        print("testing")
    
    '''
    Visualization
    '''
    
    else:
        # do thing
```

I get a red squiggly under my `else`.
Why is this?

I understand that ''' can also be used for function annotation. Is it not supposed to be used anywhere else?

Suggestions for alternative ways to highlight organization of code? (My IDE literally highlights ''' in **yellow** which I have been using organize different sections of my code.)

Comment: you can use `#` for single line comments, which appears to fit the need here

Comment: triple quotes should be used for multi-line comments. Note, they are not technically comments, they are executable code, they are simply string literals (although, the string objects are cached by the compiler). As such, your if-else statement gets broken.

Comment: Using triple quotes creates an object. Placing an object between your `if/else` results in the block being broken. A single line comment (`# …`) is what you should use in this example. Alternatively, put your triple quoted "comment" inside the else block.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Triple quotes for multi-line comments in general? Or just for docstrings? If you mean in general, that sounds really unusual.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I would only use them for doctrings, but they can be used for multi-line comments. I generally avoid that, but I would say it is at least a reasonable use-case

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yeah, with "can be" (rather than the "should be") I agree.

Answer (score 6):

Triple quotes represent a string literal, not a comment, so by placing the `Visualization` outside the `if` block with the same level of indentation you are effectively ending the `if` statement, so the following `else` clause becomes invalid. Indent `Visualization` inside the `if` block to avoid such an error.

Answer (score 2):

**Only use triple-quotes for docstrings** (or else other multiline strings, which are rare).

**Don't try to use them for comments. Use `# your comment goes here...`**

```
def do_something(test_option=False):
    """
    function to do something
    :param test_option: bool
    :return: None
    """

    # Testing
    if test_option==True:
        print("testing")

    # Visualization
    else:
        # do thing
```

(Note by the way that comments are more compact)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that Python thinks that you've ended the if statement. You went back an indent to put your comment in, so it has invalid syntax.  Try this:

```
def do_something(test_option=False):
    """
    function to do something
    :param test_option: bool
    :return: None
    """

    '''
    Testing
    '''

    if test_option==True:
        print("testing")

        '''
        Visualization
        '''

    else:
        # do thing
        pass
```